# Spring / hibernate - handling duplicates

Tags: spring, hibernate, duplicates

I have problem with handling duplicate entry in DB. I've travers throught the Google and Stack, and I didn't found working solution.

Here is my code:

DB:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `batch`;
    CREATE TABLE `batch` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `batch_number` int(3) NOT NULL,
        `batch_style` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
        `batch_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
        `batch_creation_date` DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        UNIQUE KEY(`batch_number`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;    

    LOCK TABLE `batch` WRITE;
```

POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="batch")
public class Batch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="batch_number")
    private Integer batchNumber;

    @Column(name="batch_style")
    private String batchStyle;

    @Column(name="batch_name")
    private String batchName;

    @Column(name="batch_creation_date")
    private LocalDate  batchCreationDate;

    Setters / Getters / Constructors / toString...
```

Controller (part of it):

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/batch")
    public class BatchController {

        @Autowired
        private BatchService batchService;

        @Autowired
        private MaltService maltService;

        @PostMapping("/saveBatch")
        public String saveBatch(@Valid @ModelAttribute("batch") Batch theBatch, BindingResult theBindingResult) {

            if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                return "batch-form";
            }
            else {
                try {
                    batchService.saveBatch(theBatch);

                    return "redirect:/batch/list";

                } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
                    theBindingResult.rejectValue("batchNumber", "duplicate", "Invalid number");
                    return "batch-form";
                }
            }
        }       

@GetMapping("/showBatchUpdateForm")
    public String showBatchUpdateForm(@RequestParam("batchId") int theId, Model theModel) {

        // get batch form our service
        Batch theBatch = batchService.getBatch(theId);

        // set  as a model to prepopulate the form
        theModel.addAttribute("batch", theBatch);

        return "batch-form";
    }
}
```

Next I have DAO and Service.
DaoImpl (part of it):

```
@Repository
public class BatchDAOImpl implements BatchDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void saveBatch(Batch theBatch) {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theBatch);
    }    
}
```

Problem:
When I edit record (ie. `batchNumber = 2`) and I just save it, leaving original number - it is ok, no exceptions is thrown.
When I try to change `batchNumber=2`, to `batchNumber=1` (number already taken), I receive exception:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'batch_number_UNIQUE'
```

I'd like to add, when I use the same approach to prevent duplication in another entity, it works, so after hours of debuging, I have no idea what is going on here. I can post whole code on github.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You are catching the wrong exception. In your controller you are catching `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` but the saving-operation throws an `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` . So basically, you just need to change the catched exception in the controller.

Comment: Actually I'm catching `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`, not the one from `java.sql` package

Comment: Ah sorry, my answer was the wrong way round. Now its correct